# How to clear messages in a channel without someone typing in a command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to make a bot that deletes everything in a channel every sunday, I have gotten the dates down but I don't understand how I can delete every message in a certain channel without someone running a command that tells the bot to delete everything, any way to do this?

My code so far

```
    import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random
import datetime
from datetime import date
import calendar


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')

has_cleaned_channel = 0
date = datetime.date(2021,4,4)
if date == date.today():
  if has_cleaned_channel == 0:
    print("Date is Sunday")
    print(date.today())
    has_cleaned_channel = 1

date2 = datetime.date(2021,4,5)
if date2 == date.today():
  has_cleaned_channel = 0


client.run("TOKEN")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, before you do anything else you need to reset your discord bot token.
You've just included it in the question and made your application vulnerable to hijacking. So please change it now!

In regards to your question, you'll want to use tasks.

```
from discord.ext import commands, tasks

@tasks.loop(hours=24)
async def daily_clean():
    channel = bot.get_channel(channelid)
    await channel.purge(limit=100)
```

Comment: Holy I forgot to substitute it with token thank you so much

Comment: Would the channel id be the name of the channel?

Comment: Nope, needs to be the channel id. You can right click the channel name on discord and "Copy ID". Just please remember to reset that token!

Comment: @MexicanTaco, [Getting discord channel id](https://github.com/5andr0/PogoLocationFeeder/issues/64#issuecomment-236785757)

Comment: Thank you so much and Yes I did reset the token

Comment: It says that bot is an unresolved reference its because it wasn't set but how can I make it work?

Comment: Does it make a difference if I write client.get_channel instead as that is the thing that works for me

Comment: No real difference